# I want to not dismiss the runtime permissions dialog when I click back button in Android 11+

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, back-button

When i Click Back Button in android 9, it doesn't do anything but in Android 11 it dismiss the permission Dialog.
Is there any solution to not dismiss the runtime permissions dialog when I click back button in Android 11+ ?

Comment: The behavior of system dialogs is up to the system. Specifically, what happens on a system BACK navigation event is up to Google and device manufacturers.